# Where is the flaw in this proof that any locally Euclidean space is Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, manifolds

Today I found myself thinking about the definition of a topological manifold $M$. Usually one requires that $M$ is locally Euclidean, Hausdorff, second countable. I began to wonder if the Hausdorff requirement was really necessary, and some time later I thought I had found a proof that if $M$ is locally Euclidean then $M$ is automatically Hausdorff. However, then I found several sources on the internet saying that this is not the case: e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold#Line_with_two_origins) is a counterexample. Below is my intended 'proof' of the statement, and I would gladly find out what the catch is!

Just to get the definitions clear, a topological space $M$ is called locally Euclidean if there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ such that every point $p$ in $M$ has an open neighborhood $U\subset M$ such that there is a homeomorphism $\phi:U\to \phi(U)$, where $\phi(U)\subset\mathbb R^n$ is open. The pair $(U,\phi)$ is called a chart.

**'Proof' that locally Euclidean implies Hausdorff.**
Let $p,q\in M$. Suppose first that there exists a chart $(U,\phi)$ containing both $p$ and $q$. Then $\phi(p)\neq\phi(q)$ so since $\phi(U)\subset\mathbb R^n $ is Hausdorff, there exists open sets $V,W\subset\mathbb R^n$, which we may assume are contained in $\phi(U)$, such that $\phi(p)\in V, \phi(q)\in W$ and $V\cap W =\emptyset$. Then $\phi^{-1}(V)$ and $\phi^{-1}(V)$ are open sets in $M$, satisfying $p\in \phi^{-1}(V)$ and $q\in\phi^{-1}(W)$ and $\phi^{-1}(V)\cap\phi ^{-1}(W)=\emptyset$.

Suppose next that there does not exists a chart containing both $p$ and $q$. Since $M$ is locally Euclidean, there must still be charts $(V,\phi)$, $(W,\psi)$ around $p$ and $q$, respectively, and $V\cap W$ must be empty, since if it weren't, then $(V\cap W,\phi)$ would be a chart containing both $p$ and $q$, contradicting our assumption.

Hence in both cases we can find the separating open sets, and therefore $M$ is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as I finished typing my question, I saw the flaw in the proof... It's in the second case, where there are charts $(V,\phi),(W,\psi)$ for $p,q$, respectively. I then claim that if $V\cap W\neq \emptyset$ then $V\cap W$ would contain both $p$ and $q$ but of course this is nonsense.

Comment: +1 It would still be nice to see an actual example of a non-Hausdorff space which is locally Euclidean and second-countable.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: There's a link in the question which describes the line with two origins.